# Any tips for connecting to browsersync running inside vagrant box?

Tags: vagrant, gulp, browser-sync, gulp-sass

I have gulp firing browser-sync when it detects css changes.

output looks like

```
[BS] [info] Proxying: http://dev.local
[BS] Access URLs:
 -------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000/cw
    External: http://10.0.2.15:3000/cw
 -------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://10.0.2.15:3001
 -------------------------------------
```

In the browser I can access `dev.local`, `dev.local/cw`, and `dev.local:3001` but **not** `dev.local:3000` or `dev.local:3000/cw`.

When I try to connect to dev.local:3000 or dev.local:3000/cw the browser just hangs waiting until eventual timeout.

I thought I may have a port forward problem in the VM so I forwarded the  port browser-sync uses in the Vagrantfile.

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000
```

Still no luck though.

my **Gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var shell = require('gulp-shell');
var notify = require('gulp-notify');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('./scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass({
      noCache: true,
      outputStyle: "compressed",
      lineNumbers: false,
      loadPath: './css/*',
      sourceMap: true
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'))
    .pipe(notify({
      title: "SASS Compiled",
      message: "All SASS files have been recompiled to CSS.",
      onLast: true
    }));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  browserSync({
    proxy: "dev.local",
    startPath: "cw"
  });

  // watch scss, js, and tpl files and clear drupal theme cache on change, reload browsers
  gulp.watch(['scss/**/*.scss', 'js-src/**/*.js', 'templates/**/*.tpl.php'], function() {
    gulp.run('sass');
  }).on("change", browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

Any ideas why I can't connect to browser-sync through the site?

Comment: Where you able to find a solution for this? i am in the same boat

Comment: I kind of gave up. But I'm actually on a project that could really use this right now. So I'll look today and hopefully report back

Comment: Anything to update?

Comment: @Uma I wish. only solution I know is to install node and run browsersync on the host unfortunately